# error: The named parameter 'title' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter at [ecommerce_flutter] lib\screens\main.dart:127)

Tags: flutter, dart

```
title: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          AppLocalizations.of(context).main_screen_bottom_navigation_home,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                      )),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
```

Comment: Add your full code snippet and refer [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

**title** is now deprecated, use **label** property instead, and just give it a String , ex: 'Home', 'Cart',..

Read : https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/bottom-navigation-title-to-label

More About [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) and [BottomNavigationBarItem](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem-class.html)

Comment: how bro help me

Comment: change `title: Text("Home")` to `label="Home"`